# Symbolic reduce on MatrixSymbol

Tags: sympy

Is there a way to express reduction operations like max, min, sum, etc. for symbolic matrices (or really just any kind of symbolic array)? Element-wise operations can be done by the following:

```
a = MatrixSymbol('a', 3, 3)
a.applyfunc(lambda x: Max(x, 1))
```

Output:

```
(d ↦ Max(1, _d))˳(a)
```

(I am a bit confused what the above expression means in a mathematical sense, what does `d` and `_d` denote?)

Ofcourse, the `as_explicit()` will return:

```
⎡Max(1, a[0, 0])  Max(1, a[0, 1])  Max(1, a[0, 2])⎤
⎢                                                 ⎥
⎢Max(1, a[1, 0])  Max(1, a[1, 1])  Max(1, a[1, 2])⎥
⎢                                                 ⎥
⎣Max(1, a[2, 0])  Max(1, a[2, 1])  Max(1, a[2, 2])⎦
```

Now, is there a way do this operation for a max reduction over the first axis? I want this output for the `as_explicit()`:

```
⎡                                                                                             ⎤
⎢Max(a[0, 0], a[1, 0], a[2, 0])  Max(a[0, 1], a[1, 1], a[2, 1]) Max(a[0, 2], a[1, 2], a[2, 2])⎥
⎣                                                                                             ⎦
```

Comment: The symbols `d` and `_d` are the same. The printing shows them as different for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Between looking at the `matrices` docs, and experimenting I came up with the following:

```
In [213]: a = MatrixSymbol('a', 3, 3)

In [214]: a
Out[214]: a

In [215]: M = Matrix(a)

In [216]: M
Out[216]: 
⎡a₀₀  a₀₁  a₀₂⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢a₁₀  a₁₁  a₁₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣a₂₀  a₂₁  a₂₂⎦

In [217]: M.row(0)
Out[217]: [a₀₀  a₀₁  a₀₂]

In [218]: Max(*M.row(0))
Out[218]: Max(a[0, 0], a[0, 1], a[0, 2])
```

This is consistent with the signature: `Max(*args)`